# String delimiters in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I'm writing a query within a module.
At the moment I'm getting a syntax error. I believe it is because I have misplaced an " to implicate a string.
However, I cannot see it. Maybe it is another error... Can anyone have a look?

Code:

```
        QryInsertTracks = "INSERT INTO IMP_TRACK_GLOBAL_INFO VALUES (" & recTracksMissing(0) & ", " & recTracksMissing(1) & ", " & recTracksMissing(2) & ", " & recTracksMissing(3) & ", " & _
            recTracksMissing(4) & ", " & "'" & fixQuotes(recTracksMissing(5)) & "' , " & "'" & recTracksMissing(6) & "' , " & "'" & recTracksMissing(7) & "' , " & _
            "'" & recTracksMissing(8) & "', " & _
            fixNull(recTracksMissing(9)) & ", " & _
            "'" & fixQuotes(recTracksMissing(10)) & "' , " & _
            recTracksMissing(11) & ", " & _
            fixNullAgain("'" & fixQuotes(fixNull(recTracksMissing(12))) & "'") & ", " & _
            "'" & recTracksMissing(13) & "'" & ", '" & recTracksMissing(14) & "', '" & recTracksMissing(15) & "', '" & recTracksMissing(16) & "', " & fixNullAgain("'" & fixQuotes(fixNull(recTracksMissing(17))) & "'") & ", " & _
            "'" & fixQuotes(recTracksMissing(18)) & "' , " & _
            fixNull(recTracksMissing(19)) & ", " & _
            "'" & fixQuotes(fixNull(recTracksMissing(20))) & "' , " & _
            fixNullAgain("'" & fixQuotes(fixNull(recTracksMissing(21))) & "'") & ", " & _
            fixNullAgain("'" & fixQuotes(fixNull(recTracksMissing(22))) & "'") & ", " & _
            fixNullAgain("'" & fixQuotes(fixNull(recTracksMissing(23))) & "'") & ", " & _
            fixNullAgain("'" & fixQuotes(fixNull(recTracksMissing(24))) & "'") & ", " & _
            fixNullAgain("'" & fixQuotes(fixNull(recTracksMissing(25))) & "'") & ", " & _
            "'" & recTracksMissing(26) & "' , " & _
            "'" & recTracksMissing(27) & "' , " & _
            fixNull(recTracksMissing(28)) & ", " & _
            fixNull(recTracksMissing(29)) & ", " & _
            "'" & recTracksMissing(30) & "' , " & _
            fixNull(recTracksMissing(31)) & ", " & _
            "'" & recTracksMissing(32) & "' , " & _
            "'" & fixQuotes(recTracksMissing(33)) & "' , " & _
            "'" & recTracksMissing(34) & "', '" & Now & "', " & fixNullAgain("'" & fixQuotes(fixNull(recTracksMissing(35))) & "'") & ", " & fixNull(recTracksMissing(36)) & ", " & fixNull(recTracksMissing(37)) & ")"
```

Comment: `I cannot see it. Maybe it is another error... Can anyone have a look?` Do you know that there is a code review site? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good luck to the next person that has to maintain this.  Perhaps it's worth refactoring this out into methods to make it more readable `AddValue(int index, bool fixQuote, bool fixNull)` - in doing so, you'll probably find (or fix) where the syntax error is.

Comment: "My God, It's full of sta.. quotes!"

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't know there was a code review site.

Answer (score 3):

1. Write `Stop` after the you have written;
2. Run the code;
3. It will stop on the `Stop` word;
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
5. Write `?QryInsertTracks` and press Enter
6. Take a look at the result - it should be visible;